# Neo4j missing a .pid file when running neo4j start

Tags: azure, neo4j

I installed Neo4j HA via Azure.

I dropped my database backup to replace graph.db folder.

However, when I try to run neo4j start, I get the following error:

`/usr/share/neo4j/bin/neo4j: line 396: /var/run/neo4j/neo4j.pid: No such file or directory`

There is no folder called `neo4j` in `var/run/`. Should this be automatically created when Azure sets up Neo4j for you?

Using `killall -9 java` didn't work, likewise with `killall -9 neo4j`.

I'd really like to assistance with this!

Comment: Are you using a pre-installed instance? Are you able to run `systemctl status neo4j.service`?

Comment: What OS is your Azure OS running on?